# Is $(\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},+)$ resp. $(\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},\cdot)$ a group?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to check whether $(\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},+)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},\cdot)$ are groups but I'm experiencing some problems.
*/By $\mathbb{R}^{n×n}$ are meant the matrices of size $n\times n$*/

So we have the four group axioms:

> (G0)   :   **Closure** $∀a,b∈G: a∘b∈G$
>   (G1)    :   **Associativity**         $∀a,b,c∈G: a∘(b∘c)=(a∘b)∘c$
>   (G2)    :   **Identity** $∃e∈G:∀a∈G: e∘a=a=a∘e$
>   (G3)    :   **Inverse** $∀a∈G:∃b∈G: a∘b=e=b∘a$

Its obvious that the first 3 axioms are satisfied for both $(\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},+)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},\cdot)$

**But does G3 holds since not every matrix is invertible?**

Answer (score 3):

I assume by $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ you mean the matrices of size $n\times n$? If so, of course it is not a group with matrix multiplication because not every matrix is invertible. However, if you take only the invertible $n\times n$ matrices then you really get a group. (which is called the general linear group)

Answer (score 2):

The set of $n\times n$ matrices over the reals is not a group with multiplication. First, the zero matrix is absorbing and second not each matrix has an inverse.
Additively, it is an abelian group.